# Is there some dead simple way to record all audio (input+output) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, audio-recording

I need a very simple app that my non-technical colleagues can use for recording calls made via a VOIP program on their PC.

There are many programs that allow recording audio input and/or output - but after a significant time of digging, I couldn't find one which with little or no configuration "just works" to record all audio input+output of the system (or at least all audio going in or out of a specific program).

On OS X there's a program called Audio Hijack Pro which is works perfectly for such needs and is a breeze to configure - is there anything similar for Win7?

Comment: Are they locked to this specific VoIP program?  There are some that support call recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Windows 7 that will allow you to do this natively, unless the hardware manufacturer created the driver with some sort of virtual "mix" interface.  Occasionally, you'll get lucky and have a sound-card that provides a "Stereo Mix" virtual interface that will allow you to loop your output back in the system as an input source... but most sound-chip manufacturers don't bother implementing that in Windows 7.   There are 3rd party tools like [VAC](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) that can do this... but they sacrifice a bit of CPU to make it happen... and they're not free.  They don't always work as nicely as you would hope either.  Give it a shot... and see what happens.

Comment: +1 for VAC, it basically is Audio Highjack Pro for windows.